# how to put a checkbox checked in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

In my laravel work admin assign roles to users.Assigning is done using checkbox.But when taking already assigned user,checkboxes are not ticked.Tick the checkboxes which are already assigned.

//controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Session;
use Redirect;
use Response;
use App\Http\Controllers\AdminController;
use App\User;
use App\Area;
use App\Http\Requests\ShopUpdateRequest;
use DB;
use App\Customer;
use App\MyRoles;
use App\Roles;
use Assets;
use Auth;
use Datatables;

class EmployeeController extends AdminController
{

    public function assignrole(){
        $title = "Prizes";  
        $post = 0;
        $count = 0;
        $employees = User::where('employee','yes')->get();
        $roles = Roles::select('roles.role_name','roles.id')->get();

        return view('app.admin.roles.assignrole',  compact('title','post','count','roles','employees'));
    }


    public function postassignrole(Request $request){
        $title = "Prizes";  
        $post = 0;
        $count = 0;
        $employee = User::where('id',$request->employee)->pluck('username');//current employee name
        $emp_id = $request->employee;//current employee id
        $roles = Roles::select('roles.role_name','roles.id')->get();//all links
        return view('app.admin.roles.postassignrole',compact('title','post','count','roles','employee','emp_id'));
    }

    public function saverole(Request $request){
        $array = $request->all();//employee id
        $emp_id = $array['emp_id'];//after assigning roles gives employee id
        $i = 0;
        MyRoles::where('user_id',$emp_id)->delete();
        foreach($array as $data){

            if($i == 0){

            }else{
                MyRoles::create(
                    [
                        'user_id' => $emp_id,
                        'role_id' => $data
                    ]
                    );
            }
            $i++;

        }
        Session::flash('flash_notification', array('level' => 'success', 'message' => 'customer created successfully'));
        return Redirect::action('Admin\EmployeeController@assignrole');
    }
}
```

//view

```
@extends('app.admin.layouts.default')

{{-- Web site Title --}}
@section('title') {{{ $title }}} :: @parent @stop


@section("styles") @parent
<style>
.material-switch > input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;   
}

.material-switch > label {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 0px;
    position: relative; 
    width: 40px;  
}

.material-switch > label::before {
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius: 8px;
    content: '';
    height: 16px;
    margin-top: -8px;
    position:absolute;
    opacity: 0.3;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    width: 40px;
}
.material-switch > label::after {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-radius: 16px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    content: '';
    height: 24px;
    left: -4px;
    margin-top: -8px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -4px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    width: 24px;
}
.material-switch > input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
    background: inherit;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.material-switch > input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
    background: inherit;
    left: 20px;
}

</style>
@stop

{{-- Content --}}
@section('main')


    <div class="page-header">
        <h3>
           Assign roles
        </h3>
    </div>
<div class="form-group">


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <label>Assign Roles of <b>{{$employee}} </b></label>
    </div>
       <div class="row">
    <form action="{{url('admin/save-role')}}" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="emp_id" id="emp_id" value="{{$emp_id}}">
            <br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10">

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Select Roles</div>

                       <ul class="list-group">
                       @foreach($roles as $data)
                           <li class="list-group-item">

                           <label><input type="checkbox"  id="checkbox{{$data->id}}" name="{{$data->id}}" value="{{$data->id}}">{{$data->role_name}}</label>  

                           </li>                
                        @endforeach
                        </ul>

            </div>  
              <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        Assign Roles 
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                        </div>

        </div>
        </form>  
    </div>
</div>

</div>

@endsection

@section("scripts") @parent
<script src="/js/color.js"></script>
    @stop
```

Comment: You need to pass list of roles already assigned before you can mark the checkboxes. I don't see you doing that at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Use query to fetch the already assigned roles for an employee selected in the previous screen. Then pass it to the view. And in assigning roles, if the role id gets matched mark it as checked.